# Is Paan considered Sattvic?

Tags: food

Is the consumption of Paan leaf allowed under the rules of a Sattvic diet, or is it prohibited?

Does it matter how it is prepared, or what other ingredients are used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Betel leaves have a pungent taste, and pungent foods are [described](http://vedabase.com/en/bg/17/9) as Rajasic, not Sattvic, in the Bhagavad Gita.  I'm not sure whether there are any scriptures that give definitive lists of foods that belong to each category, but in any case [this page](http://ayurveda-foryou.com/treat/foodtemparament.html) and [this page](http://www.newindianexpress.com/lifestyle/article429979.ece?service=print) both classify betel leaves as Rajasic.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say anything about paan as it is not mentioned in any of the scriptures and it is a by product of the ancient mouthfreshner known as tambul or tambool which is dry and is prepared for rituals nowadays and even during Havan or Yagna.

The process is after the panchopchaar pooja in which 5 elements in different forms are offered to the diety, at last a mukprakshalan stuff is given known as tambool.

[this](http://khaugiri.blogspot.in/2009/02/tambul.html) page teaches everything about tambul it's ingredients and recipies

So as devi devtas eat it, it is a sattvic product but only if you follow rules of tambul not the wet paan we see nowadays, It contains many harmful substances like the pan-masala and other chemical sweeteners which are carcinogenic in nature.

Comment: "So as devi devtas eat it, it is a sattvic product" No, just because a food is offered to the gods doesn't mean that it's a sattvic food.  You could offer foods of other gunas to the gods as well.

Comment: It is sattvic because of it's ingredients it dosen't makes any one feel tamas(lazy,and ignorant)or rajasic(aroused or anxious).It gives you peace after food that's why it is given as prasad and eaten after that